# Run code before before block

Tags: rspec

Rather than do this:

```
subject { response }
context 'when orphan' do
  before do
    post :create, asset: { parent_id: nil, uploaded_file: file }
  end

  it { should have_http_status 201 }
  it { should redirect_to_location '/' }

  it 'create a asset' do
    expect { post :create, asset: { parent_id: nil, uploaded_file: file } }.to change(Asset, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
subject { response }
context 'when orphan' do
  before do
    post :create, asset: { parent_id: nil, uploaded_file: file }
  end

  it { should have_http_status 201 }
  it { should redirect_to_location '/' }

  it { should create_an(:asset) }
end
```

To do this I'll have to create a custom matcher:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :create_an do |instance| 
    match do |actual|

        #### ALL I NEED IS A WAY TO TRIGGER THIS LINE
        #    BEFORE THE BEFORE BLOCK
        # before_before do
               number_before = count_records
        # end       
        ##############################################
        number_after = count_records

        number_after - number_before == 1
    end

    def count_records
        instance.to_s.classify.constantize.count
    end  

    failure_message_for_should do |actual|
        "..."
    end

    failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
        "..."
    end

    description do
        "should create an #{instance.to_s}"
    end
end
```

Like I say, all I need to do is run:

```
number_before = count_records
```

before the before block,

```
  before do
    post :create, asset: { parent_id: nil, uploaded_file: file }
  end
```

is run. Is this possible? Any ideas? Any hooks rspec provides for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to implement what you've asked for, but the following does reduce some duplication.

```
context 'when orphan' do
  let(:create) { post :create, asset: { parent_id: nil, uploaded_file: file } }

  context 'the response' do
    before { create }
    subject { response }

    it { is_expected.to have_http_status 201 }
    it { is_expected.to redirect_to_location '/' }
  end

  it 'creates a asset' do
    expect { create }.to change(Asset, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Peter. I've upvoted this but not accepted this as I want to issue a bounty. If noone responds to the bounty I'll accept this again. Hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 1):

Use time state, add extra variable

```
time_b=0 
 do
 number_before = count_records
time_b!=0
do 
  number_after = countrecords
 before do
post :create, asset: { parent_id: nil, uploaded_file: file }
 end
```

This should solve the prolem.