# Mock specific instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Here's the trivial code I'm testing:

```
def inside
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @locations = @location.inside
end
```

And here's the expectation:

```
describe '#inside' do
    # objects
    let(:location){            FactoryGirl.create(:location, longitude: 5, latitude: 5, radius: 5) }
    let(:location_inside){     FactoryGirl.create(:location, longitude: 6, latitude: 5, radius: 1) }
    let(:location_not_inside){ FactoryGirl.create(:location, longitude: 10, latitude: 10, radius: 1) }

    # request
    let(:request){ get :inside, id: location.id }

    describe 'response' do
        before do
            location.should_receive(:inside).and_return([location_inside])
            request
        end

        specify{ expect( assigns :location).to eq location }

        specify{ expect( assigns :locations).to include location_inside }
        specify{ expect( assigns :locations).to_not include location_not_inside }
        specify{ expect( assigns :locations).to_not include location } # a bug I was getting
    end
end
```

It passes perfectly if I'm not mocking the `location` instance. However, I want to mock but I can't because this happens:

```
Failure/Error: airspace_one.should_receive(:inside).and_return([location_inside])
       (#<Location:0x0000000325ddb8>).inside(any args)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Now, it's obvious why this is happening. I think it's because the `location` created by FactoryGirl is an identical but seperate instance of Location. So how am I meant to mock the instance in my code base? I could use `any_instance_of`, but apparently that's a smell?

Comment: What's `airspace_one`?

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry, edited. It's `location`

Comment: You seem to missing a verb in your second to last sentence: "how am I meant to ... the instance in my code base".

Comment: @PeterAlfvin It's 'Mock' :) btw I owe you some rep: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493253/run-code-before-before-block if you edit that answer I can choose your answer.

Comment: @Starkers Oh, hi. Didn't look at your name. :-) Not sure about the relationship between editing and choosing answers, but I did just make a minor edit to that answer.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin For some reason it wouldn't let me accept it unless you edited again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test the behavior of your `inside` method, you can set an expectation on `Location` to return your instance, as in:

```
expect(Location).to receive(:find).with(location.id).and_return(location)
```

Comment: Great! Where do you put your mocks? I put them inside every context's before block, before the request. Is that what you do?

Comment: I'm still trying to find my RSpec "style" in that and other regards, but I think that's a fine place to put them.